# How to quantify basic levels of samples in qPCR?

Tags: pcr

I do have to quantify the difference in basic levels of expression for a given gene in two types of tissues. There is no treatment, just basic levels.

Before I had a "control" sample that I taken as a "1", then a "treated" sample was calculated based on that control (its values were subtracted), therefore a fold change could be calculated between two types of tissue.

Now there's no fold change, just bare numbers, so I wonder how we suppose to quantify delta-deltaCT ? (what are these references?)

Comment: a hint - reference gene... You can easily find the original paper on the d-dCT method with a pubmed search.

Comment: if you mean the housekeeping gene - of course, I have it. That is how my delta CT is calculated.

Comment: yes, reference = housekeeping. In that case I don't think I understand what your question is. You either do a relative quantitation by d-dCT or an absolute using a standard curve. It looked to me like you were asking to how to do d-dCT.

Comment: correct. d-CT is calculated via housekeeping. But when it gets to d-dCT, this is the question. Maybe I just need to compare dCTs between two tissues? This will give me the "raw" number relatively to housekeeping gene.

Comment: d-dCT is calculated by comparing your treatment to the control - if you don't have a control then you need to look at your experimental set-up and ask yourself what are you actually looking at (what are you aiming to find out) and what might be an appropriate analysis. This isn't the site to ask those sorts of questions on - check with your supervisor or another student in your lab.